# The function to calculate differential/derivative in DM

Tags: dm-script

I remember that is a function to calculate the differential/derivative for a line plot in a DM version, it looks lik in the process- non linear filter- derivative. But I do not remember which version has this function, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI functionality for spectral filtering is found in the **Spectrum** menu:
[image: Spectrum menu]

Since GMS 3 this functionality is part oft the free software, before it was part of the Spectroscopy license (any). 
The menu only works on line profiles which are *spectra*, for which the *Convert Data To* menu would be used when required.

As all "menu" commands, you can access them using the `ChooseMenuItem` command as in:

```
GetFrontImage().SelectImage() // Make sure the image window is selected, or the menu is disabled if the script-window is frontmost!
ChooseMenuItem("Spectrum","Numerical Filters","First derivative")
```

---

The mathematical functions behind this menu are also available as (unofficial, undocumented) script commands. They do not use the preferences but the parameters directly, using uncalibrated 'channel' scale.
So you could also use:

```
image src := GetFrontImage()
number chWidth = 5  // The values matching the settings
number chDelta = 1  // The values matching the settings
number chShift = trunc((chWidth + chDelta)/2 + 0.5)
number norm = chWidth + chDelta 
image fDev := src.FDeriv_Spectrum( chWidth, chShift, norm )
fDev.ShowImage()
```

Just be warned that there is no guarantee that the command `FDeriv_Spectrum` will be continued in future versions of GMS (It is not an officially supported command.)

---

Finally, the math of a first derivative are really simple, so you could just recreate the function with pure DM-script commands like `offset` and arithmetic operators.
A simple, non-smoothed 1-channel derivative would simply be:

```
image src := GetFrontImage()
image fdev := src - src.offset(-1,0)
fdev.ShowImage()
```

Comment: My current version of DM, it does not have the menu/function of "spectrum", it may due to its a free version, could I download the plugin of the "spectrum" somewhere? Thanks,

Comment: @together Go to [http://www.gatan.com/installation-instructions](http://www.gatan.com/installation-instructions) and make sure you get the "SI Viewer" license (right-most column) in STEP 1. All the licenses in that table are free - and I think you can combine them, so you might also want the STEMx license if diffraction-imaging is of interest to you. The latest installer (currently 3.3) is then downloaded under Step 2.